# How do you define a model for a User-to-User relationship in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Normally in EF you can use

```
ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

to define a users relationship to the property. But I am getting confused how to do it for a property between two users, if that makes sense? Basically I want to define a model for relationships between users e.g.

UserA and UserB has the following relationship:

```
bool Friends { get; set; }
bool Blocked { get; set; }
```

I am also wondering how's best to model it for this "Blocked" property. Because I want both to be able to block each other and unblock. e.g. UserA blocks UserB. Then he decides to unblock, and so the Blocked property changes from true to false. BUT if UserB also blocked UserA, the property remains true.

EDIT 28/07

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
         ...
         public virtual ICollection<UserRelationships> Relationships { get; set; }
}

 public class UserRelationships
    {
        public int UserRelationshipsId { get; set; }
        public UserRelationships() { this.Friends = false; this.Blocked = false; }
        public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
        public bool Friends { get; set; }
        public bool Blocked { get; set; }
        public string Blocker { get; set; }
        public string SecondBlocker { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need `ICollection<ApplicationUser> BlockedUsers {get;set;}` on your entity model. Also another collection for friends. When someone tries to access UserA's page, just do a check the application user is not in UserA's block list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a many-to-many (pure join) in EF, but it ONLY tracks Left and Right ID, nothing else. So, if you wanted to audit the time of the friendship or block, you would have to do so in another table.

Instead, I would encourage you to use the following structure:

```
public class ApplicationUserRelationship
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser LeftUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser RightUser { get; set; }
    public virtual RelationshipType RelationshipType { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You could of course replace `RelationshipType` with a `string` or set of `bool` as you have done (`IsFriend`, `IsBlocked`) or an `enum` if it makes sense.

In your `ApplicationUser` you now have:

```
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRelationship> ApplicationUserRelationships { get; set; }
```

Then in fluent:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
             .HasMany(u => u.ApplicationUserRelationships)
             .WithRequired(u => u.LeftUser);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
             .HasMany(u => u.ApplicationUserRelationships)
             .WithRequired(u => u.RightUser);
```

Comment: thanks tacos, I'll post what I have when I get home tonight. I think this is nearly it, but I don't want a "owning" and dependent user. I want merely users to share properties, otherwise there will be data duplicates. Thinking about it though, maybe this is the best option with regards them blocking each other. I'll have a think, thanks again

Comment: @user2330270 no problemo, see my edit. I made a mistake in the beginning for sure, trying to suit the Left/Right-ness to a purpose for which it was not designed. I believe this is the correct Fluent configuration. It's weird to see it this way but I believe it is valid, because these are configuring class-level properties, not instance-level properties.

Comment: I have thought more about this, and posted what mess I had last night. How would I get the relationship though? Could you add an example? I have a unit of work method with a .get(). Can post a new question if required

Comment: @user2330270 I would be happy to do so but I need a little more background about your unit of work impl. The idea here is that a "relationship" is a first-class object, with a left/right side, and a modifier for type of relationship. So you would create your users first of course, then if you wanted to glue them together you make a new relationship object whose left and right are users. Then you save the relationship to the appropriate `DbSet`

Comment: yeah I thought I might, I will write it up tonight and link :) thanks!